# Spark losing println() on stdout

Tags: scala, apache-spark, println, accumulator

I have the following code:

```
val blueCount = sc.accumulator[Long](0)
val output = input.map { data =>
  for (value <- data.getValues()) {
    if (record.getEnum() == DataEnum.BLUE) {
      blueCount += 1
      println("Enum = BLUE : " + value.toString()
    }
  }
  data
}.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)

output.saveAsTextFile("myOutput")
```

---

Then the blueCount is not zero, but I got no println() output! Am I missing anything here? Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

This is a conceptual question...

Imagine You have a big cluster, composed of many workers let's say `n` workers and those workers store a partition of an `RDD` or `DataFrame`, imagine You start a `map` task across that data, and inside that `map` you have a `print` statement, first of all:

- Where will that data be printed out?
- What node has priority and what partition?
- If all nodes are running in parallel, who will be printed first?
- How will be this print queue created?

Those are too many questions, thus the designers/maintainers of `apache-spark` decided logically to drop any support to `print` statements inside any `map-reduce` operation (this include `accumulators` and even `broadcast` variables).

This also makes sense because Spark is a language *designed* for very large datasets. While printing can be useful for testing and debugging, you wouldn't want to print every line of a DataFrame or RDD because they are built to have millions or billions of rows! So why deal with these complicated questions when you wouldn't even want to print in the first place?

In order to prove this you can run this scala code for example:

```
// Let's create a simple RDD
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 10000)

def printStuff(x:Int):Int = {
  println(x)
  x + 1
}

// It doesn't print anything! because of a logic design limitation!
rdd.map(printStuff)

// But you can print the RDD by doing the following:
rdd.take(10).foreach(println)
```

Comment: I believe println works just fine: it just goes to the stdout /stderr on the computer that is running a spark executor.  So unless you have a way to capture what is in those logs you will never see it.  If you are using yarn there is a command to print it all out for you however.

Comment: While argumentation is valid Spark doesn't perform any type of static analysis to drop code. Output just doesn't go to the driver `STDOUT` as explained by @David

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work it around by making a utility function:

```
object PrintUtiltity {
    def print(data:String) = {
      println(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Because Spark thinks it is calling an Utility function instead of calling the print function. Spark apparently didn't (and couldn't practically) check every line in its utility function.

Comment: What you are doing is instantiating an object in your driver program.  I would not count on this behavior without a clear model of exactly what is going on.  Expect the behavior to change unpredictably with any change to your program or how you invoke the PrintUtility object.  If you want to collect logs, use standard methods to do it, don't invent random mechanisms that you don't understand.  Your explanation for why it works is dangerously wrong - there is no prohibition from doing what you did; there is no code checker to make sure you don't cheat: all behavior follows system design