# How to use existing trained model using LinearRegressionModel to work with SparkStreaming and predict data with it

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, linear-regression

I trained data using LinearRegression and saved the model, now I am trying to use this in SparkStreaming and predict the data using it, but my program does not predict the data, other lines fetching data from stream and everything works in loop but prediction does not work, Can anyone help me with the prediction of data?

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("streamingApplication")    
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc,Seconds(60)) 



val finalData = data.map{
                      x => LabeledPoint(x.price , Vectors.dense(x.timestamp,x.volume,x.volume,x.price))
                    }                                   


        val model = LinearRegressionModel.load(sc, "linearReg")
        finalData.map{
            points => val prediction = model.predict(points.features)
            println(points.label)
            println(prediction)
            (points.label, prediction)
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the prediction does not work"?

Comment: println(points.label)
            println(prediction)

Does not print anything

Comment: What's `data`? Is it possible there's nothing in it? Also you may be experiencing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225994/spark-losing-println-on-stdout

Comment: no there is datat in it, i printed it

   val finalData = data.map{
                          x => LabeledPoint(x.price , Vectors.dense(x.timestamp,x.volume,x.volume,x.price))
                        }                                 
                     
finalData.print()

I used this and it prints data all the time but when it is passed for prediction ,nothing is printed

Comment: Try `finalData.map{println("Hello world")}` and see the question I linked to

Comment: What worked? Please add some more detail for future readers of this question

Comment: You mean the code was working, it was just the println output wasn't appearing?

Comment: Yes it was, println was done separately and not where prediction is done