# Passing function in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

The purpose of the code is to load compute some logic based on the "myFunc" method that operated on RDD to get parallelization benefit.

The following lines :
df_rdd = ParallelBuild().run().map(lambda line: line).persist()
r = df_rdd.map(ParallelBuild().myFunc)

gave me exit 0. Reading google suggested that Spark is lazy evaluation so some action will trigger the effect and i add :

r.count() gives me :

```
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

Noticeable thing was that :
r = df_rdd.map(ParallelBuild().myFunc)

gives "pipelinedrdd" not sure what that is but looks like some transformation?

Interesting part was that when I removed run method and implemented:
data = [(1,'a'), (1,'b'), (1,'c'), (2,'d'), (3,'r'), (4,'a'), (2,'t'), (3,'y'), (1,'f')]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema= ['uid', 'address_uid'])

directly in my main function then things worked just fine. But obviously i loose modular part of my code.

Code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, HiveContext
import csv, io, StringIO
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import asc, desc
sc = SparkContext("local", "Summary Report")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


class ParallelBuild(object):

def myFunc(self, s):
   l =  s.split(',')
   print l[0], l[1]
   return l[0]


def list_to_csv_str(x):
    output = StringIO.StringIO("")
    csv.writer(output).writerow(x)
    return output.getvalue().strip()

def run(self):
    data = [(1,'a'), (1,'b'), (1,'c'), (2,'d'), (3,'r'), (4,'a'), (2,'t'), (3,'y'), (1,'f')]
    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema= ['uid', 'address_uid'])
    return df


if __name__ == "__main__":

    df_rdd = ParallelBuild().run().map(lambda line: line).persist()
    r = df_rdd.map(ParallelBuild().myFunc)
    r.count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your main question is "Why isn't anything printing?" There are two parts to the answer.

1. You can't really `print` in distributed computing. So your function `myFunc` won't print anything to the driver. The reason for this is rather complicated, so I direct you to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225994/spark-losing-println-on-stdout) for more information on why printing doesn't really work in Spark.

*However*, calling `r.count()` should print out `9`. Why doesn't that work?

2. Your function `myFunc` doesn't make much sense. When you call it in `r = df_rdd.map(ParallelBuild().myFunc)`, you're passing in the `df_rdd`, I think. But this is already a DataFrame. Each row of this DataFrame is of type `Row` and if you call `df_rdd.first()` you will get `Row(uid=1, address_uid=u'a')`. What you are doing in `myFunc` is an attempt to use `split`, but `split` is for string objects, and you have `Row` objects. I'm not sure why this isn't throwing an error, but you simply can't call `split` on a `Row` object. Consider something more along the lines of `r = df_rdd.map(lambda x: x[0])`.

So, I think `r.count()` doesn't work because something is getting muddled when you call `myFunc`.

---

Side note:

`df_rdd = ParallelBuild().run().map(lambda line: line).persist()`. Running `.map(lambda line: line)` doesn't do anything. You're not making any changes to `line`, so don't run a `map` job. Have the code be `df_rdd = ParallelBuild().run().persist()`