# Scala seemingly ignoring some code

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is pretty strange to me. I am familiar with the differences between `map` and `foreach` in Scala and the use cases for both but perhaps I don't understand something else. I first ran into this when I was playing around with Spark so it's possibly this only manifests itself when I am using an RDD.

Here is the following code in which the call to map is seemingly ignored.
I am using Scala 2.11.1 and here is my dependencies for running the following code.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"
)
```

The below can  be pasted in a scala console

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner

val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Test")
val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)


val rdd: RDD[Tuple2[String, String]] = sc.parallelize(List(
  ("I", "India"),
  ("U", "USA"),
  ("W", "West")))

val rp = new RangePartitioner(3, rdd)
val parts = rdd.partitionBy(rp).cache()

parts.mapPartitionsWithIndex( (x,y) => { y.map(println); y } ).collect()
```

When running this you can see that nothing is printed to stdout. However if you change the last line of code to `parts.mapPartitionsWithIndex( (x,y) => { y.map(println) } ).collect()` or even this `parts.mapPartitionsWithIndex( (x,y) => { y.foreach(println); y } ).collect()` it will be printed.

I believe this is different then the question about stdout not being output since I am in local mode and this is an issue with evaluation of the RDD not stdout.

Comment: In what case exactly it does not gets printed ?

Comment: In the full code example with the imports nothing is printed to stdout. Possibly it's a setup issue though if you are able to see something in stdout for every example.

Comment: Are you running this on local ? And plz specify the case in which it does not run with the exact code difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark losing println() on stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225994/spark-losing-println-on-stdout)

Comment: `RDD` are lazy data structures. So no actual computation will happen untill you "consume" from a `RDD`. Here your consumption by `collect()` forces the `RDD` to really evaluate itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the function passed into `mapPartitionsWithIndex` is `(Int, Iterator[T]) ⇒ Iterator[U]`  so in your example, `y` is an `Iterator`

In Scala `Iterator` is a lazy collection, in other words it doesn't do any work until a result is needed (similar to an RDD).

In your code `(x,y) => { y.map(println); y }`  The map transformation returns a new `Iterator` where each element, when evaluated, will be printed out and replaced with `Unit`.  You then discard this iterator and return the original, making the output `RDD` identical to the input.  Since the iterator produced by map is never used, the function is never evaluated and nothing is printed.

In your "working" codes, `(x,y) => { y.map(println)}` applies the same mapping transformation, but returns the iterator it produces.  So when you evaluate the `RDD` you create from the transformation (using `collect`), the lines are printed (also notice that the resulting `RDD` will contain all `Unit` values).

In the other example, `(x,y) => { y.foreach(println); y }`  You instead use `foreach` which evaluates each element of the iterator strictly, and returns Unit. You then return the input iterator (which is now empty, as you've already consumed all of the elements).  When the `RDD` is evaluated with `collect`, this block is run and the elements are printed, notice how the resulting `RDD` is empty.

Comment: Sorry, but briefly that because first case doesn't contain `action` and second does ???

Comment: @cue action is a spark specific term and here we are talking about `Iterator`, so plain old scala.  It is basically the same idea though.  `map` on an iterator does nothing immediately, but returns a new iterator where each element will have the function passed into map applied to it *when evaluated*.  If you never do anything with the iterator that gets returned the code in the `map` never runs.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this! I understood the lazy evaluation of spark to some extent but didn't realize it also applied to children RDDs which makes sense. Mostly I wasn't thinking that the partition was also returning an RDDs... which of course after reading your answer makes sense as well.

Comment: @mschuett I need to reiterate, this specific problem has nothing to do with spark or RDDs, Iterator is a standard Scala class, it just also has similarly lazy semantics