# Why is the code inside RDD.map not executed in YARN?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I use Hortonworks 2.6 with 5 nodes. I `spark-submit` to YARN (with 16GB RAM and 4 cores).

I have a RDD transformation that runs fine in `local` but not with `yarn` master URL.

`rdd1` has values like:

```
id  name    date
1   john    10/05/2001 (dd/mm/yyyy)
2   steve   11/06/2015
```

I'd like to change the date format from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `mm/dd/yy`, so I wrote a method `transformations.transform` that I use in `RDD.map` function as follows:

```
rdd2 = rdd1.map { rec => (rec.split(",")(0), transformations.transform(rec)) }
```

`transformations.transform` method is as follows:

```
object transformations {
  def transform(t: String): String = {
    val msg = s">>> transformations.transform($t)"
    println(msg)     
    msg
  }
}
```

Actually the above code works fine in local but not in cluster. The method just returns an output as if the `map` looked as follows:

```
rdd2 = rdd1.map { rec => (rec.split(",")(0), rec) }
```

`rec` does not seem to be passed to `transformations.transform` method.

I do use an action to trigger `transformations.transform()` method but no luck.

```
val rdd3 = rdd2.count()
println(rdd3)
```

`println` prints the count but does not call `transformations.transform` method. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** Enable Log Aggregation in Hadoop and use `yarn logs -applicationId` to see the logs (with `println` in the logs of the two default Spark executors). Don't forget to bounce the YARN cluster using `sbin/stop-yarn.sh` followed by `sbin/start-yarn.sh` (or simply `sbin/stop-all.sh` and `sbin/start-all.sh`).

---

The reason why you don't see the `println`'s output in the logs in YARN is that when a Spark application is `spark-submit`'ed to a YARN cluster, there are three YARN containers launched, i.e. one container for the ApplicationMaster and two containers for Spark executors.

`RDD.map` is a transformation that always runs on an Spark executor (as a set of tasks one per RDD partition). That means that `println` goes to the logs of executors.

NOTE: In `local` mode, a single JVM runs both the driver and the single executor (as a thread).

To my surprise, you won't be able to find the output of `println` in the ResourceManager web UI at http://localhost:8088/cluster for the Spark application either.

[image: RM's web UI]

What worked for me was to enable log aggregation using [yarn.log-aggregation-enable](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) YARN property (that you can read about in the article [Enable Log Aggregation](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.0/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/ref-375ff479-e530-46d8-9f96-8b52dadb5183.1.html)):

```
// etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml
<property>
  <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-aggregation.roll-monitoring-interval-seconds</name>
  <value>3600</value>
</property>
```

With that configuration change, you simply `spark-submit --master yarn` to submit a Spark application followed by `yarn logs -applicationId` (I used `yarn logs -applicationId application_ID > output.txt` and reviewed `output.txt`).

You should find `>>> transformations.transform(1,john,10/05/2001)` there.

### The Code

The code I used was as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object HelloRdd extends App {

  object transformations {
    def transform(t: String): String = {
      val msg = s">>> transformations.transform($t)"
      println(msg)
      msg
    }
  }

  val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
  val rdd1 = sc.textFile(args(0))
  val rdd2 = rdd1.map { rec => (rec.split(",")(0), transformations.transform(rec)) }
  rdd2.count()
}
```

The following is the `spark-submit` I used for testing.

```
$ HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/tmp ~/dev/apps/spark/bin/spark-submit \
  --master yarn \
  target/scala-2.11/spark-project_2.11-0.1.jar `pwd`/hello.txt
```

Comment: Its Printing now..! Thank you

Comment: It did print, but the way **we** looked at this problem was wrong (!) I hope we all learnt something new today. Thanks.

Comment: I have a global variable in DVT `object` called `element` its carrying empty value i.e `List()` in cluster is ter any fix. `trait variables {
  val element: List[List[String]] = List()
}` In transformations page i used like DVT.element but its returning empty value in cluseter

Comment: Please ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't provide enough information, and

> Yes, I did in local its working fine its executing the if loop but in cluster else is executed

is contradictory to

> the method inside the map is not accessible while running in cluster

If it's executing the `else` branch, it doesn't have any reason to call the method in the `if` branch, so it doesn't matter whether it's accessible.

And if the problem was that the method is inaccessible, you'd see exceptions being thrown, e.g. `ClassNotFoundException` or `AbstractMethodError`; Scala wouldn't just decide to ignore the method call instead.

But given your code style I am going to guess that `transformation` is a `var`. Then it's likely that code which sets it isn't executed on the driver (where the `if` is executed). In local mode it doesn't matter, but in cluster mode it just sets the copy of `transformation` on the node it's executed on.

This is the same issue described at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#local-vs-cluster-modes:

> In general, closures - constructs like loops or locally defined methods, should not be used to mutate some global state. Spark does not define or guarantee the behavior of mutations to objects referenced from outside of closures. Some code that does this may work in local mode, but that’s just by accident and such code will not behave as expected in distributed mode.

Comment: Actually the `transformations.transform` method is called inside the if loop and its also coming inside if loop but instead of entering in to the transformation method it just executed as `.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0), rec))` instead of `.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0), transformations.transform(rec)))`

Comment: So is there any alternative to call `transformations.transform` inside map

Comment: Another possibility is that `transformations.transform` _used_ to be defined differently and you have a JAR with the old version on the node for some reason.

Comment: `println("from transformations")` its not printed inside transformations method..!

Comment: If that's why you think it isn't getting executed, this is wrong, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225994/spark-losing-println-on-stdout#comment62643591_33226090.

Comment: Do we have any alternative way to call that method in map or using any method.

Answer (score 0):

> > Why is the code inside RDD.map not executed with count?
> >     I want to change the date format from (dd/mm/yyyy) to (mm/dd/yy), so using a method called transform inside transformations(object) in map() function

**If you are looking to change the dateformat only**, then I would suggest you **not to go through such complexities** as its very difficult to analyze the cause of the issue. I would *suggest you to apply dataframes instead of rdds* as there are many *inbuilt functions to meet your needs*. For your specific requirement `to_date` and `date_format` *inbuilt functions* should do the trick

First of all, *read the data to dataframe* as

```
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .load("path to the data file")
```

Then just apply the `to_date` and `date_format` functions as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("date2", date_format(to_date(col("date"), "dd/MM/yyyy"), "MM/dd/yy")).show(false)
```

and you should get

```
+---+-----+----------+--------+
|id |name |date      |date2   |
+---+-----+----------+--------+
|1  |john |10/05/2001|05/10/01|
|2  |steve|11/06/2015|06/11/15|
+---+-----+----------+--------+
```

**Simple** isn't it?