# How do I manage print output in Spark jobs?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, stdout

I'd like to view the output of `print` statements in my Spark applications, which uses Python/PySpark. Am I correct that these outputs aren't considered part of logging? I changed my `conf/log4j.properties` file to output to a specific file but just the INFO and other logs are being written to the designated log file.

How do I go about directing the output from `print` statements to a file? Do I have to do the typical redirection like this: `/usr/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --queue default /home/hadoop/app.py > /home/hadoop/output`?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225994/spark-losing-println-on-stdout?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Not the same question @Sc0rpion